# Numba cuda dynamic shared memory: more than one type?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am aware that I can create a dynamic shared memory array for a numba-compiled CUDA kernel by passing the size in as the forth argument to the kernel call:

```py
    ...
    foo_kernel[grid, block, stream, shared_bytes](...)
    ...

@cuda.jit
def foo_kernel(...) -> None:
    a = cuda.shared.array(0, nb.int32)
```

From here, I can slice `a` if I want to treat as several arrays.

However, what if I want to have two arrays of different dtypes? Can I do something like:

```py
    ...
    a = cuda.shared.array(0, nb.int32)
    b = cuda.shared.array(0, nb.float32)
    ...
```

and then slice `b` so that I access values appropriately non-overlapping with `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Aha -- some googling finds: https://curiouscoding.nl/posts/numba-cuda-speedup/#v15-dynamic-shared-memory

Which confirms that different dtypes are indeed supported, using the trick I guessed (as pictured above).

Comment: Please don't add link only answers. When that blog goes away your answer becomes useless without the salient information in your answer

Comment: The question was asking for confirmation - it included a potential answer, and asked if it was correct. I found the confirmation and linked to it; the answer remains embedded in the question. So, most succinctly, the answer is "yes".